# problem with run a c++ code with eclipse che on ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, eclipse-che

run eclipse che by browser in ubuntu 
when i run this code

```
#include <iostream>

main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0; }
```

i got this error

> cd /projects/my_prj && make && ./a.out
>
> make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

what can i do for solve it?

[image]

Comment: Write a makefile. Or `make hello`. And use `int main()`.

Answer (score 0):

To test that the required tooling is installed, try running this in the terminal:

```
cd /projects/my_prj
g++ -o a.out main.cc
```

(or whatever you called the C++ file you wrote above).

If you want a Makefile to build the project, you will need to specify a target (the default target will be "all") which has a rule for compiling the C++ code into a binary. The minimum would be something like this:

```
all:
     g++ main.cc
```

Put this in a file called Makefile, and make sure that the 2nd line starts with a real tab, not an expanded one, and you should be good. There is a lot more to learn about Makefiles, but this will get you started.